# perl configuration file which contains variables?

Tags: perl, configuration, configuration-files

I want to create a perl configuration file.  I want a file format which has variables.  So something like this:

```
DefaultDirectory = /var/myProgram/
OutputDirectory = $DefaultDirectory/output
InputDirectory = $DefaultDirectory/input
```

This seems simple, but I'm not sure what is available with perl.  The perl ini options I see don't appear to support it. I looked into YAML, but it seems almost overkill.

Can anyone suggest a good file format and CPAN module that supports it which can support simple variables?  I'm stuck with perl 5.5 so hopefully an older module.

Comment: [AppConfig](https://metacpan.org/pod/AppConfig) can do this, but the way your question is worded makes it sound like you're asking people to recommend a module, and is therefore in danger of being flagged as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Config::General](http://search.cpan.org/~tlinden/Config-General-2.60/General.pm).

test.cfg

```
# Simple variables
DefaultDirectory = /var/myProgram
OutputDirectory  = $DefaultDirectory/output
InputDirectory   = $DefaultDirectory/input

# Blocks of related variables
<host_dev>
    host     = devsite.example.com
    user     = devuser
    password = ComeOnIn
</host_dev>

<host_prod>
    host     = prodsite.example.com
    user     = produser
    password = LockedDown
</host_prod>
```

test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::General;

my $conf = Config::General->new(
    -ConfigFile => 'test.cfg',
    -InterPolateVars => 1
);

my %config = $conf->getall;

print <<HERE;
    Default directory: $config{'DefaultDirectory'}
    Output directory: $config{'OutputDirectory'}  
    Input directory: $config{'InputDirectory'}    

    Development host: $config{'host_dev'}{'host'}
    Development password: $config{'host_dev'}{'password'}

    Production host: $config{'host_prod'}{'host'}
    Production password: $config{'host_prod'}{'password'}
HERE
```

Output:

```
Default directory: /var/myProgram
Output directory: /var/myProgram/output
Input directory: /var/myProgram/input

Development host: devsite.example.com
Development password: ComeOnIn

Production host: prodsite.example.com
Production password: LockedDown
```

Comment: can't locate method getAll via package config::General::interpolated.  I have clearly not learned perl yet; because I don't even understand why it is looking at interpolated rather then config::General lol.  but after I fix capitlization this seems to work :)

Comment: Config::General::Interpolated is a module that is automatically called when you create a new Config::General object and specify the -InterPolateVars flag.  Normally you can't have variables in your config file like $DefaultDirectory, but the -InterPolateVars flag gives that ability.  See http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-General/General/Interpolated.pm   (and yes, capitalization is important!)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just writing your own perl module that contains config?

Something like (`MyConfig.pm`):

```
package MyConfig;
our $DefaultDirectory = '/path/to/somewhere';
our $setting_for_something = 5; 

1;
```

You can then import that with `use MyConfig;`. You may need to set `use lib` or `FindBin` to find the module first though (depends on where you invoke the script - `use` will search cwd).

But really - perl `5.5`? That's .... well worth updating, given that's the version from 2004. I do hope you don't run too much stuff on 10 year old software - the world has changed A LOT in the intervening time. (And so has Perl)

Comment: trust me, I want to upgrade.  But the problem is that the development system is used by so many that no one is willing to change anything.  the obvious thing would be to move away from that box entirelyl but...not my choice sadly.

Comment: *shrug*. I can't make you do it, but you should probably note - you can run multiple versions of perl with perlbrew, or just simply installing a new perl in `/usr/local` (which is the default location) instead of `/usr/bin`.